# Funnel object into another

Tags: objects

What is the most practical way to funnel a 3d model into another by vertex count? The purpose of it, is to have a creature absorb objects by suction, mildly deforming the sucking creatures opening as the object is forcefully drawn inside?

Comment: what do you mean "by vertex count"? Is it the creature who absorbs who is deformed or also the objects (other creatures?) he absorbs? Perhaps show a screenshot of your creature... maybe the Mesh Deform modifier could work for the absorbed objects?

Comment: Whatever the object is, gets compacted down the creatures gullet with mild deformation on the creatures mouth and throat. same way a fish do. but the object actually crunching, buckling and compacting into shape as its forcefully sucked inside. visualize a catfish with huge fleshy lips, the size of a house devouring a school bus, but in a sucking manner, as the bus crumples inward into the monsters maw.

Comment: https://youtu.be/2J5Db146mJA?t=224    


For Reference

Comment: yes, so Mesh Deform modifier sounds good to me, do you know how it works?

Comment: Not in the intended way, I do not. I'll look into it more. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a solution with the *Mesh Deform* modifier:

- Create your object.
- Create a cube that contains your object as a cage, subdivide it. In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display*, enable *Draw All Edges* and *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire* so that your cube is in wire mode.
- Give your object a *Mesh Deform* modifier. Put it above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Choose the cube as the *Object*, and click *Bind*.
- Select the cube. In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create one Shape Key (it will be called *Basis* by default), then a second one.
- Keep this second Shape Key selected. Go in *Edit* mode. Sculpt your cube (with *Proportional Editing* activated) so that it deforms your object the way you want.
- Come back in *Object* mode. Now you can play with the *Value* of each Shape Key and insert Key Frames so your object is deformed the way you want at the moment you want on the Timeline.

[image]

Comment: This example will be a tremendous help. thank you so much for explaining it to me. works just as it does in Max.